# How can I add my tasks back to my list using Restangular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, restangular, spring-data-rest

So here's the flow that I'd like request wise, intial page load -> get tasks -> add task. add task, should not require a subsequent fetch of it's created task or the list.

here's the relevant part of my app.js thus far

```
.config(function (RestangularProvider) {
RestangularProvider.setBaseUrl('http://localhost:8080');
RestangularProvider.addResponseInterceptor(function halInterceptor(data, operation, what) {
  var resp;

  if (operation === 'getList') {
    if (typeof data._embedded !== 'undefined') {
      resp = data._embedded[what];
      resp.page = data.page;
      return resp;
    }
    else {
      return [];
    }
  }

  return data;
});
})
```

here's my controller

```
'use strict';
angular.module('myTaskApp')
.controller('Task', function ($scope, Restangular) {
var tasks = Restangular.all('task');

if ( typeof $scope.tasks === 'undefined' ) {
  $scope.tasks = tasks.getList().$object;
}

$scope.add = function add() {
  tasks.post($scope.task).then(function () {
    console.log('add task: ', $scope.task);
    // MAGIC HERE
  });
 };
})
;
```

Here are the response headers for  a create

```
HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-: POST, GET, PUT, OPTIONS, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: content-type, x-requested-with
Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600
Location: http://localhost:8080/task/5c75235d-d9f7-4cdd-98b4-3487603d8fcb
Content-Length: 0
Date: Sat, 20 Sep 2014 06:34:59 GMT
```

I think that part of my problem is that the response doth not return the body, however, I can predict what that should look like, and would be easy to craft after grabbing location.

```
{
"description" : "better",
"_links" : {
  "self" : {
   "href" : "http://localhost:8080/task/5c75235d-d9f7-4cdd-98b4-3487603d8fcb"
  }
 }
}
```

how can I make it so that when I create a new resource I can then add it to the `$scope.tasks` list and have that reflected in my `ng-repeat`. Again, this should be without making further calls to the API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having updated my provider, which now contains a `selfLink` definition and a `post` handler. I retrieve the location from the response and construct a partial response object.

```
.config( function ( RestangularProvider ) {
RestangularProvider.setBaseUrl( 'http://localhost:8080' );
RestangularProvider.setRestangularFields({ selfLink: '_links.self.href' });
RestangularProvider.addResponseInterceptor( function halInterceptor( data, operation, what, url, res ) {
  console.log( data, operation, what, url, res );

  if ( operation === 'getList' ) {
    if ( typeof data._embedded !== 'undefined' ) {
      var resp = data._embedded[ what ];
      resp.page = data.page;
      return resp;
    }
    else {
      return [];
    }
  }

  if ( operation === 'post' && res.status == 201 ) {
    return {
      _links: {
        self: { href: res.headers('Location') }
      }
    };
  }

  return data;
} );
```

Then in my controller all I have to do is use `angular.extend` to combine the response and create a "smart object"

```
angular.module('lifeManagerApp')
.controller('Task', function ($scope, Restangular) {
var tasks = Restangular.all('task');

if ( typeof $scope.tasks === 'undefined' ) {
  $scope.tasks = tasks.getList().$object;
}

$scope.add = function add() {
  tasks.post($scope.task).then(function ( task ) {
    var obj = angular.extend($scope.task, task);
    console.log('add task: ', obj );
    $scope.tasks.push(obj);
  });
};
});
```

It's worth noting that for my stuff I also had to [update CORS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18178524/206466) and make sure [my controller wasn't loading multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16589743/206466)